# C++, оптимизация сложного возвращаемого значения

Tags: c++, return, value

Меня интересует вопрос, касающийся оптимизации сложного возвращаемого значения.

Например, ситуация такая:

```
class Bound
{
    public:
    // ...
    float getTop() const;
    float getRight() const;
    float getBottom() const;
    float getLeft() const;

    private:
    // ...
    float top;
    float right;
    float bottom;
    float left;
};

class Object
{
    public:
    // ...
    Bound getBound() const;
    private:
    // ...
    Bound bound;
};

void some_function()
{
    Object object;
    // ...
    const float top = object.getBound().getTop();
}
```

Действительно ли для строки:

```
const float top = object.getBound().getTop();
```

Компилятор способен убрать все лишние операции, в том числе операции копирования того, что мне не нужно?

Во многих библиотеках (в той же `SFML`) составные объекты возвращаются в виде копии. Это выглядит так, словно для получения значения одного поля приходится делать копию всего объекта вместе со всем его содержимым, которое мне не нужно.

От такого кода сишник внутри меня яростно негодует...

Comment: Я бы не рисковал, и возвращал константую ссылку.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, я бы тоже, если бы библиотеки, которыми я пользуюсь, были бы написаны мной.

Comment: Я поигрался с `g++ -O... -S -c ...` с вашим примером и некоторыми его модификациями. Конкретно в вашем коде копирование (запись в память 2-х xmm регистров) после вызова `getBound()` происходит и в `getTop()` в качестве `this` передается адрес копии. Однако, если добавить к полям класса поле `int x`, то копирования уже нет и в `getTop()` передается тот же `this`, что и в `getBound()`. / Т.е. кресты как всегда, непредсказуемы

Comment: @avp За это я их и люблю :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Действительно, способен, но это не гарантируется.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow на русском! Постарайтесь, пожалуйста, оставлять чуть более подробные ответы.

Answer (score 1):

Вы  легко можете проверить сами, проверяя что выполняется, если не отладчиком, не ассемблером, то немножко изменив код:

```
struct F {
    float f = 0.1;
    F() = default;
    F(const F&) {  std::cout << "FCopy\n"; }
};

class Bound {
public:
    // ...
    Bound() = default;
    Bound(const Bound&) 
    { std::cout  << "BCopy\n";}
    F getTop() const
    { return top;}
private:
    // ...
    F top;  
};

class Object
{
public:
    // ...  
    Bound getBound() const
    { return bound; }
private:
    // ...
    Bound bound;
};
int main() {    
    Object object;  
    const float top = object.getBound().getTop().f; 
    return 0;
}
```

На консоли будет виден результат  копирований.

Comment: Конструктору не следует иметь побочных эффектов. Что касается печати строки при вызове конструктора - компилятор может напечатать строку, но выкинуть все, что не используется в каждом конкретном случае конструирования. Теоретически.

Comment: @MGNeo, конструктор копирования или вызывается или не вызывается.  Мы просто проверяем вызывается или нет. Если да, то будет вызываться и  без данного определения, а если вызывается, значит копирование происходит. Не может он копировать только часть членов.  В выводе строки нет никаких побочных эффектов. Вы хотите сказать, что  конструктор копирования может не вызываться, если  он генерируется по  умолчанию?...

Comment: У `Yandex`-а есть очень интересное видео с конференции, на которой русскоязычная международная рабочая группа по стандартизации (`WG21`) обсуждает развитие идеи пропуска копии. Компилятор может не просто выкинуть большую часть кода, он может перенаправить конструирование полей в другие расположения - сразу туда, где они нужны. Что-то может переиспользовать. Очень интересно и сложно. Рекомендую посмотреть.

Comment: То есть, при вызове конструктора или любого другого метода/функции, для каждого конкретного случая может генерироваться свой вариант кода. И в этом коде с высокой степенью вероятности будет меняться содержание и порядок инструкций.

Comment: Нет. Добавление определенного пользователем конструктора запросто может поменять и поведение класса в рамках компиляторных оптимизаций. Поэтому оценивать оптимизации таким способом совершенно бесполезно.